# VPD PROBLEM: ORA-28113: policy predicate has error

Tags: sql, oracle

write a policy function as scott to implement the following policy: Users can access only the data of their own, but sysdba should be able to access any data without restrictions, then attach the policy to the table.?(THE table name is RATING, and one column name is NAME)

```
SCOTT > CREATE FUNCTION POLICY (
p_schema IN VARCHAR2,
p_object IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
BEGIN
if(SYS_CONTEXT('userenv', 'SESSION_USER') = 'SYS' ) THEN RETURN '';
else 
RETURN 'NAME = SYS_CONTEXT ("USERENV", "SESSION_USER")';
END IF;


SYS AS SYSDBA> EXECUTE DBMS_RLS.ADD_POLICY (object_schema=>'SCOTT', OBJECT_NAME=>'RATING', POLICY_NAME=>'FIRST_POLICY', FUNCTION_SCHEMA=>'SCOTT', POLICY_FUNCTION=>'POLICY', STATEMENT_TYPES=>'SELECT', UPDATE_CHECK=>TRUE);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

ERROR: `SCOTT > SELECT * FROM RATING;`

SELECT * FROM RATING * ERROR at line 1: ORA-28113: policy predicate has error

Comment: It appears that your predicate is using the double quote character " rather than using two single quotes ''.  I assume your intention there was to use two single quotes in order to escape the single quote you want in the result.

Answer (score 2):

I see three things:

1. there is no point in checking for `SESSION_USER='SYS'`, as SYS is exempt from all VPD policies by definition; this will *never* be true.
2. double-quotes identify labels, not literal input values. Change your double-quotes to single quotes.
3. You didn't properly close out your function. Make sure you have an `END;` statement.

Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION POLICY (
  p_schema IN VARCHAR2,
  p_object IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN 'NAME = SYS_CONTEXT (''USERENV'', ''SESSION_USER'')';
END;
```